# Python - Linking columns in Excel for sorting

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

**The problem that I have to solve:**

I'm trying to automate several processes in excel. I'm currently stuck on the first one. (Also I'm pretty weak at using excel so I apologize in advance if some of the things I saw don't make sense. I scraped data from the internet and inputted into an excel file. I concat'ed that data with a spreadsheet I already had. Here's the code I used to combine files.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def MergeFiles():
    #find both csv files on computer
    baseData = pd.read_csv('pathname') #keep this on the left
    scrapedData = pd.read_csv('pathname') #keep this on the right


    mergedFile = pd.concat([baseData, scrapedData], axis = 1)

    mergedFile.to_csv('pathname', index = False)

MergeFiles()
```

**What I want to do:**

Col1 Col2

c      1

b      2

a      3

-Alphabetically Order Col 1 and values in col2 also shift

Col1 Col2

a      3

b      2

c      1

**I'm trying to link columns together so if I try to sort all rows go through the same position shift.**

Also any help would be appreciated, I tried looking into Pandas documentation and I couldn't find anything related to this problem. I probably missed something so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the pandas library does all of this automatically through sort_values()

So

```
scrapedData = scrapedData.sort_values(by = ['colName'], ascending=True,) #sort the scrapedData
    scrapedData.to_csv('pathName', index = False) #replace the file
```

would do the trick